# プログラムを、自分のホームディレクトリにある特定のファイル群に書き込めないよう実行したい

Tags: linux

`~/Pictures/backup/` というディレクトリの下に写真がたくさんあります。Permission はこのようになっています

```
  $ ls -l IMG_0944.JPG 
-rw-r--r-- 1 Yosh Yosh 2192854 Mar  2  2019 IMG_0944.JPG
```

写真の整理をしたくて、とりあえずこのディレクトリにあるファイルの exif 等をよんでデータベースを作るようなプログラムを作成しました。このプログラムは既存の画像ファイルを読み込むだけで、上書きしたり消去したりはしないはずですが、もしかすると自分がバグを作り込んでいて、そうした挙動をしてしまうかもしれません。

写真のデータが失われることは絶対に避けたいので、何らかの方法で実行時にこれらのファイルへの書き込み・消去ができないような（しかしこのプログラムが作るデータベースは書き込めるような）制限をかけられないかと思いました。このようなうまい方法はあるでしょうか？あるいは、同様の目標を達成するために一般に用いられる他の方法がありますか？（バックアップをとっておくことは勿論自明で重要な解決策ですが、それはさておき）

環境は Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS です。

Comment: すべての写真を読み出し専用にしてはだめなのでしょうか？chmodでできると思いますが？

Comment: @池田茂樹 ありがとうございます、大変理にかなっている…のですが、今は特定のプログラムを実行するときだけ保護する方法を探しています。10^3個のファイルに対して、プログラム実行前に読み出し専用にして、実行後戻すようなやりかたは普通でしょうか？（経験がなく全くわからないので、純粋な質問です）

Comment: どんな方法で EXIF を読み取るのか分かりませんが、大抵のプログラミング言語ではファイルの操作時に「読み込み専用」「読み書き可」のモードを選択できるはずなので、通常はこの部分で対応すれば十分な気がします。 / 慎重なのは悪いことではありませんが、後はまずダミーのデータで動作確認することでしょうか。 / 実行の前後でパーミッションをいじるのは、結局この操作もバグの生まれる要素の一つになり得る気がします。

Comment: 「このディレクトリにあるファイルの exif 等をよんでデータベースを作るようなプログラム」を
Yosh以外のユーザで実行すれば、読み込みは可能書き込みは不可になりますが、それだと問題があるようであれば、要件を質問に加えた方がよいです。

Comment: そのディレクトリにあるファイルを全て別のディレクトリにコピーして、コピーしたファイルのパーミッションを読み込み専用にする。exif等を読むのはコピーしたファイルからのみにする。そうすれば、元のディレクトリにあるファイルに書き込まれる可能性はなくなりませんか？

Comment: AppArmor を利用することで実現可能かもしれません。こちらの記事 [Ubuntu 18.04: AppArmorで強制アクセス制御](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/06/ubuntu-1804-apparmor-ja/) を参考にしてみて下さい。

Comment: スペックが良く分からないので、何とも言えませんが、1000個程度のファイルでしたら、chmodで変更するのはさほど時間はかからないのではないかと思います。
私の環境では数分レベルでした…が、こればかりはその環境でやってみないと分かりませんね。

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます、仰るとおりなんですが、今後プログラムが大きくなったときに心配になってきそうで、いわば型安全な言語が提供してくれるような安心感が欲しい気持ちでした。不安がりすぎかもしれません。

Comment: @akiraejiri  システムに関することにあまりに無知で発想できていなかっただけです…。おそらく求めているもののように思うので、回答にしていただければ承認します。（ちなみに、1つのプログラムの実行のためにユーザを追加することはよく有ることなのでしょうか？: ある種の濫用なのかどうかを気にしています）

Comment: @Fumu7  全バックアップは確かに一番シンプルで確実ですね。それと別に、プログラム実行で原理的にファイルが書き込まれないやり方が何かあればということを考えていました。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます、はじめて知りましたが、調べると結構細かい設定ができるようですね。機能的にも想定された使い方の1つのような気がします。

Comment: @AgeofDiscovery 調査ありがとうございます、参考になります。そもそも a-w で有るべきようにも思えてきました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

別ユーザでプログラムを実行することにより、ファイル書き込みでエラーにすることができます。

```
$ ls -l testfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tst tst 19 Jul 15 23:47 testfile
$ cat testfile
テストデータ
```

testfileの所有者はtstで、otherの書き込みパーミッション(w)がないため、tstユーザ以外のユーザはこのファイルに書き込むことができません。

testfileに書き込むプログラムprg.shを別ユーザ(tst2)で実行してみます。

【prg.sh】

```
#!/bin/sh
id
echo "BUG" > ./testfile
```

prg.shの実行結果

```
$ su tst2 ./prg.sh
Password:
uid=1002(tst2) gid=1002(tst2) groups=1002(tst2)
./prg.sh: line 3: ./testfile: Permission denied
$ ls -l testfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tst tst 19 Jul 15 23:47 testfile
$ cat testfile
テストデータ
```

prg.shの3行目の`echo "BUG" > ./testfile`でエラーが発生しています。
testfileはタイムスタンプ、内容とも変化していません。

---

コメントにあるYoshさんの懸念ですが、

> ちなみに、1つのプログラムの実行のためにユーザを追加することはよく有ることなのでしょうか？: ある種の濫用なのかどうかを気にしています）

この仕組みはもともと他のユーザに修正させたくないためのものですので、本来の使い方であり、濫用とは思えません。
※ユーザが多数の場合はメンテナンスの手間を考えるかもしれませんが、今回のケースでは問題にならないと思います。

検証に使用した環境はWSLの`Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`です。